# MCO and EMD-S- How to use

Tags: exchange, cancellations, price, travel-agents

Hi Travel Professionals!

(this question is addressed to travel profedsionals)

I am looking to better understand the process of filing MCO (Miscellaneous Charge Orders) vs. filing an EMD (electronic miscellaneous documents carriers).

I have booked a non refundable international flight. I then found out that the price dropped by $400. The ticket is non ref but the change fee is $100.

As far as I understand, I can get a credit refund on US based flights (in ARC) that will give me the ability to reprice a ticket using only the change fee and not the cancellation fee.

As for my example: I booked a ~$2000 ticket from SFO to LHR on AA, the price of the ticket dropped to ~$1600- I can reissue the ticket on and re-price it using only the change fee **even for non-refundable tickets?**

- Does this make sense? what are the limitation and what is the process of such a thing?
- And how do I use it in the BSP (Billing & Settlement Plan) platform?

Comment: Travel SE is oriented towards travelers not travel agents.  There are some travel pros amongst the regulars here who may chime in with an answer, but it is not really the place to learn about the backend systems of a travel agency and airline.

Comment: What is MCO? EMD? ARC? BSP? FYI we (mostly) are not travel professionals here so there's a high chance you might not get an answer to your query. Please help us understand it better by adding some details.

Comment: @JoErNanO - Even knowing what they are (MCO - Misc Charge Order, EMD - Electronic Misc Document, ARC - Airline Reporting Corp, BSP - Billing & Settlement Plan) doesn't help much unless you are well versed in travel agency backend systems.

Comment: @Tom Maybe. But someone on this site might be well versed in travel agency backend systems. Could you please edit the question adding these details?

Comment: @JoErNanO improved the question. i hope it will be approved now.

Comment: @IshaiAnkri splendid. Reopened. FYI the acronym ARC is still missing an explanation.